# Array_Rand always returns same value PHP fetch array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, random

I have this function:

```
function set_spell() {
global $connection;
$query = "SELECT * FROM Spells";
$result_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$spell_id_list = mysqli_fetch_array($result_set);
return $spell_id_list;
```

Then I try to output a random ID from the array, but I always get ID 1.

```
$spell_id_list = set_spell();
echo $spell_id_list[array_rand($spell_id_list)];
```

When I run this query in MYSQL, I get a list of all ID's as expected. Why doesn't the code above select one at random?

This is probably a stupid questions that I'll smack myself after I see the answer... but I've been stuck for longer than I think I should be on it.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What you want to achieve ? Array of random result or just one random value ?

Comment: Don't use `global`, instead pass the `connection` as a param

Comment: It's been a while, but doesn't *_fetch_row just get one result? So doesn't $spell_id_list only have on item when set_spell is returned?

Comment: Trying to grab a single random ID from the array. @Mr. Alien how do I do that instead of using global? Yes, typo on the fetch_row, i tested w/ fetch_array and same problem.

Answer (score 2):

You just returning only single result from your function so either create array of all fetched results & return the same, or simply use order by `rand()` in your query,

```
SELECT * FROM Spells ORDER BY RAND();
```

Comment: Yeh, originally did w/ ORDER BY RAND() in the MYSQL statement but heard that wasn't totally random or good practice. How do I create the array with ALL fetched results vs. one? As I said in the comment above, I used msqli_fetch_array and still get the same?

Comment: Just loop over `mysqli_fetch_array` & built a resultant array.